# SQL SELECT 3 consecutive records with the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I want to select 3 consecutive (by year) records with same value from 'participation' table (name, year) :

```
Name    Year
-------------
Carol   1999
Carol   2000
Carol   2001
Carol   2002
Faith   1996
John    2001
John    2002
John    2003
John    2009
Lyla    1994
Lyla    1996
Lyla    1997
```

Here is my initial code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.name, p1.year
FROM participatition p1,
     participatition p2
WHERE (p1.year = p2.year + 1 OR p1.year = p2.year - 1) AND p1.name = p2.name
ORDER BY p1.name, p1.year
```

which returns ALL consecutive records but I only want records which meet 3 consecutive criteria, ie not Lyla:

```
Name    Year
-------------
Carol   1999
Carol   2000
Carol   2001
Carol   2002
John    2001
John    2002
John    2003
Lyla    1996
Lyla    1997
```

Is it possible to build on my code, eg add an extra criterion, to refine the selection without implementing the `row_number()` method?

I would like the following output:

### Name

Carol
John

ie all records if there are at least 3 consecutive

Comment: what should the output look like exactly? should it list only 3 records or all records if there are at least 3 consecutive. its not crystal clear what the output should be given the input

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Why is Lyla in the expected result, when you say "not Lyla"?

Comment: With *modern* join syntax jarlh refers to the syntax we have been using for about the last thirty years as opposed to your comma separated joins that were used in the 1980s :-)

Comment: Why `DISTINCT`? Can there be multiple rows with the same name and year in the participatition table? Or is it just because the join can create duplicates?

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: Apologies for missing details, I have added required output and clarified consecutive means by year

Answer (score 6):

Consider it as a gaps-and-islands problem and use the following *trick* to group consecutive rows together:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, Year - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Year) AS grp
    FROM t
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, grp) AS grp_count
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE grp_count >= 3
ORDER BY Name, Year
```

If you look at the values in `grp` column you will find the pattern.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c7fbbd47742ad7b76378673afbabe46c)

Comment: Your groups are incorrect, because different names can become the same group. Please see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91f1c8ed6aefcd60fe571af3b7a43769

Comment: Great. This makes this a great solution, because unlike my query yours is not restricted to a few consecutive rows but easily extendible.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply use `lead()`:

```
select distinct name
from (select p.*,
             lead(year, 2) over (partition by name order by year) as year_2
      from participation p
     ) p
where year_2 = year + 2;
```

For each row, this looks at the row two ahead for the same name ordered by year.  If that row is the current year plus 2, then you have three years in a row.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no duplicate years for each Name, you need `LEAD()` window function to check for the 2nd next row.
If the year in that row is equal to the current year + 2 then this means that for this Name there are 3 consecutive years:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, LEAD(Year, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Year) next_next
  FROM participatition
)
SELECT DISTINCT p.* 
FROM participatition p INNER JOIN cte c
ON p.Name = c.Name AND p.Year BETWEEN c.Year AND c.next_next
WHERE c.next_next = c.Year + 2;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ca39e3e800b21f1cfed4c9dcaddebd8).

Comment: This does, however, also output John|2009 which is not part of one of the consecution blocks.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I thought the output would be all the rows for each Name that has 3 consecutive years. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant way. But, well, this is what I've come up with:

```
select name, year
from
(
  select 
    name, year,
    case when lag(year, 2) over (partition by name order by year) = year - 2 then 1 else 0 end +
    case when lag(year, 1) over (partition by name order by year) = year - 1 then 1 else 0 end +
    case when lead(year, 1) over (partition by name order by year) = year + 1 then 1 else 0 end +
    case when lead(year, 2) over (partition by name order by year) = year + 2 then 1 else 0 end +
    1 as consecutive_rows
  from participatition
) analyzed
where consecutive_rows >= 3
order by name, year;
```

If the table participatition can contain multiple rows for one name and year, add `DISTINCT` to the subquery (aka derived table).

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT name
         , year-lag(year,2) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ASC) as two_years_ago
    FROM t
)
SELECT name, two_years_ago 
FROM cte
WHERE two_years_ago=2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In most cases, code-only answers suffer from their lack of explanation; consider explaining how this answers the question to add value for other users down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using [row pattern matching](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/ogb-appreciation-day-sql-pattern-matching-match_recognize-use-cases) if you're using Oracle Database:

```
with rws as (
  select 'Carol' nm, 1999 yr from dual union all
  select 'Carol' nm, 2000 yr from dual union all
  select 'Carol' nm, 2001 yr from dual union all
  select 'Carol' nm, 2002 yr from dual union all
  select 'Faith' nm, 1996 yr from dual union all
  select 'John' nm, 2001 yr from dual union all
  select 'John' nm, 2002 yr from dual union all
  select 'John' nm, 2003 yr from dual union all
  select 'John' nm, 2009 yr from dual union all
  select 'Lyla' nm, 1994 yr from dual union all
  select 'Lyla' nm, 1996 yr from dual union all
  select 'Lyla' nm, 1997 yr from dual 
)
  select * from rws match_recognize (
    partition by nm
    order by yr
    all rows per match
    pattern ( init cons{2} )
    define
      cons as yr = prev ( yr ) + 1
  );
  
NM            YR     
Carol       1999 
Carol       2000 
Carol       2001 
John        2001 
John        2002 
John        2003
```

Comment: This does look DBMS specific, though. The OP has not yet told us which DBMS they are using.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my initial code Group By and Having clause as below builds on the existing code (which filtered all consecutive name, year) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.name
  FROM participatition p1, participatition p2 
  WHERE (p1.year = p2.year+1 OR p1.year = p2.year-1) AND p1.name = p2.name
  GROUP BY p1.name
  HAVING COUNT(p1.name) > 2
  ORDER BY p1.name, p1.year
```

Thanks for all the answers - I never realised there was so many alternative solutions which has opened my eyes.

Comment: Why do you stick to this outdated join syntax? This is an inner join, so use `INNER JOIN`. Then, why `DISTINCT`? You group by name and select the name. So how can there be possibly duplicates that you must remove? There can't. At last, your `ORDER BY` clause renders the query invalid. You order by year, but after grouping by name, there is no year in the data set you can sort by. You could sort by `MAX(year)` or `MIN(year)` or some other aggregate, but not by year, because there can be multiple years per name. If your DBMS allows that, then the DBMS is flawed.

Comment: The only DBMS I know of allowing the invalid `ORDER BY` clause is MySQL set to cheat mode, i.e. without the proper `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'`. When using MySQL in that botch mode, it picks a value arbitrarily, i.e. converts `p1.year` to `ANY_VALUE(p1.year)` silently. Which DBMS *are* you using? As to the `ORDER BY`: remove the year anyway, because it makes no sense at all; you cannot sort a list of distinct names that is ordered by name any further.

Comment: You are correct Thorsten in guessing MySQL. I will try again in PostgresSQL and try to better understand your additional comments. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my code based on feedback (distinct, inner join, etc) from @ThorstenKettner using PSQL this time

```
SELECT p1.name
  FROM participation p1
  JOIN participation p2 ON p1.name = p2.name
  WHERE (p1.year = p2.year+1 OR p1.year = p2.year-1)
  GROUP BY p1.name
  HAVING COUNT(p1.name) > 2
  ORDER BY p1.name
```

This seems to work fine, is easy to understand and less complex. However I would like to test all solutions so I may apply such instead to suit new requirements. So thank you all for your generous help. Esp. Danke TK!

Comment: Change of mind : actually my above revised code is not 100% correct and works by happy accident - maynot work on other data. Having looked at @GordonLinoff  lead() solution and studied how lead/lag works, I think this is the most elegant solution. Thanks indeed Gordon.